# Solving a quadratic equation with parameters for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^{ 2 }+3x-a^{ 2 }-5a-4=0$$

How do I go from here? I don't know how to right away apply the quadratic formula here nor do I know how to simplify it into a way which I could easily factor it.

Although I do see how it could turn into $x(x+3)-[(a+4)(a+1)]=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-a^2-5a-4$ is just a constant, and you can treat it as with a normal constant term: complete the square in $x$ to find
$$ a^2+5a+4 = (x+3/2)^2 -9/4, $$
and then
$$ (x+3/2)^2 = a^2 + 5a + \frac{25}{4} = (a+5/2)^2. $$
Hence
$$ x = -\frac{3}{2} \pm \left(a+\frac{5}{2}\right). $$

Comment: @Kaster It makes no difference, since the $\pm$ is there: no matter what the sign of $b$, $\pm b$ covers both possible square roots of $b^2$.

Comment: Ha ha, you're right. Didn't think about it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense up to the last step. I don't understand how you get from $(x+1.5)^2 = (a+2.5)^2$ to the last thing you wrote.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Take square roots of both sides. Since $b^2=c^2 \implies b=c$ or $b=-c$, we account for both in the same way that we do with the quadratic formula. Then subtract the $3/2$ from both sides.

Comment: I obtain $x + \frac{3}{2} = \pm \big|a + \frac{5}{2}\big|$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's the same thing: $\pm ( -b) $ gives the same two numbers as $\pm b$.

Comment: I just realized that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to solve for $x$ in terms of $a$. Recall the standard form for a quadratic: $ax^2 + bx + c$. If you let $c = a^2 + 5a + 4$, then your quadratic becomes $x^2 + 3x - c$. You should be able to solve it from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
The discriminant (which depends on $a$) is a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+3x=a^2+5a+4$$
$$(x+\frac 3 2)^2=(a+\frac 5 2)^2$$
$$x=-\frac 3 2 \pm (a+\frac 5 2)  $$
$$x=a+1 \text{ or } -a-4$$

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for your reminder,